# Is it common practice to "abuse" loops as goto

Tags: c++, c, coding-style

If in code there are many if-clauses and execution of code is not sensible on a previous error, is it OK to use a one-cycles loop for this? Simply for being able to exit the block with a break?
Like this:

```
do {
    //..code
    if (error1) break;
    //..code
    if (errorN) break;
    //do finally something when no errors before
} while (false);
```

Comment: This is very common.

Comment: "similar" question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507518/what-are-some-better-ways-to-avoid-the-do-while0-hack-in-c.

Comment: In theory (and dependig on the variables around) you could also just wrap it in a function and "return" instead of break. But this kind of still would result in the same: Leave the scope.

Comment: @stefaanv Indeed! Will close this, thank you!

Comment: I remembered the question because I'm one of the many answerers.  However, I don't think it's duplicate, otherwise I'd voted to close immediately.

Comment: Indeed. This is about "common practice" not alternatives.

Comment: It is common practice, but for maximum portability, the end condition should be written `while (0);`

Comment: @Bathsheba Probably you are right, however the other question offered what I wanted to know also. Thank's for answering in any case!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is idiomatic, even if, perhaps, it was not the intended use for a `do` `while` loop. The source code for the linux kernel exploits this.

There's nothing unclear about it: `while(false)` does exactly what is says on the tin.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning linux kernel!

Comment: What's the advantage of such a technique instead of checking for `! error` and executing the code inside of an `if` block ?

Comment: Well then, you have to have a suitable `error` around in scope, and `if` doesn't have a `break`.

Comment: @Thomas If there are multiple places where you need to check for error, then you need to duplicate the code you'd place in your `if` block.  Typically a single-entry, single-exit approach is simpler in C and allow consolidating cleanup code.

Comment: I had the impression that `goto cleanup` was more widespread then `do while(0)` in the linux kernel.   Things could have changed since I looked at some linux kernel code or it may depend on experiences...

Comment: @Bathsheba @jamesdlin I was talking about using nested `if` statements checking for `!error_n` without loop instead of creating a one iteration loop with `if` checking for `error_n` to break the loop.

Comment: @ThomasWilmotte When you have to do a lot of such checks, then all of the nested levels of indentation are cumbersome and harm readability.  You either have to scroll horizontally (yuck) or wrap lines earlier than you otherwise would. (Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18507973/179715 )

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's a common technique to avoid deep nesting, and actually preferable to `goto;`.

From point of readability its way better than `goto` statements. The scope and code flow of the loop is well defined, and you don't need to lookup the corresponding labels of the `goto` statements, which not necessarily appear below.

Comment: why preferable to goto? Doesn't it have exactly the same effect?

Comment: @tobi303 It guarantees scope, and is better readable. With a `goto` statement you have to lookup the corresponding label (wich doesn't necessarily appear below the statement).

Comment: @tobi303 mentioning the (perfectly legal) keyword `goto` always risks starting a religious war. It's just one of those infectious dogmas that make their way into the human mind.

Comment: _"The scope and code flow of the loop is well defined"_ Just as it is with `goto`, at least in C++; [to believe otherwise is to buy into a common misconception](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7334968/560648).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: nice plug for your excellent answer ;-)

Comment: @Bathsheba: Shame I can't take it to the bank ^_^

Comment: I disagree about preferability. `goto error`/`goto failure`/`goto cleanup` clearly documents the intent better than a bare `break` statement.  IMO excessive indentation (which would happen due to the gratuitous `do`-`while` block) also harms readability.  As for having to look for the `goto` labels, that's an apples to oranges comparison.  The context of the question is about cases where a `goto` is interchangeable with breaking out of a loop.  Finally, you can't directly use the `break` method if you're already within a loop or `switch` statement.