# Using goto for optimization

Tags: c++, goto

Hi i was wandering if using goto is good practice for optimization. i know it's a barbarian thing to do but, seriously.

for instance write this:

```
switch(command[0].cmd)
{
    case 0: // turn off
        s::s_off();
        S_time = command[0].length;
    break;
    case 1: // turn on
        s::s_on();
        S_time = command[0].length;
    break;
    case 4: // nop

    break;
}
```

like this:

```
switch(command[0].cmd)
{
    case 0: // turn off
        s::s_off();
        goto a;
    break;
    case 1: // turn on
        s::s_on();
        goto a;
    break;
    case 4: // nop
        goto b;
    break;
}

a:
S_time = command[0].length;
b:
```

Comment: No. There are very, very, very few cases where you actuall need to use `goto` and it's not for optimization. Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379172/use-goto-or-not

Comment: *"i know it's a barbarian thing to do"* - Have you actually read Dijkstra's famous paper, or are you going by the title alone as most people do?

Comment: No. It's almost never a good idea, even for "optimization".

Comment: Ever heard of functions?

Comment: In this particular case it's probably better to extract bodies of `case 0` and `case 1` as a function

Comment: @StoryTeller no but i'll give it a try :D

Comment: In the specific case with the code shown, some are recommending breaking out the common code into a function. I instead think you should refactor the code as `if` statements, and then just let the compiler handle the optimizations needed (which it might handle just fine even with the `switch` statement, look at the generated code with compiler optimizations enabled).

Comment: Good when you do. Keep goto in your tool box for the very rare occasion you'd really need it (this isn't it, and in C++ you'll unlikely to ever). If this was C, there are some cases where goto's actually make code better (by being used in a structured manner).

Comment: @StoryTeller for illustration purposes I think this article sums it up quite nicely: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/04/27/using-goto-for-error-handling-in-c

Comment: No its not a good Idea but not evil though.. Any specific reason why you considered `GOTO`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended to use `goto` frequently. But it is not "evil" and in many cases is much easier to put 1 goto instead of more complex logic only to avoid the "evil". And in your example single goto is enough:

```
switch(command[0].cmd)
{
    case 0: // turn off
        s::s_off();
        break;

    case 1: // turn on
        s::s_on();
        break;

    case 4: // nop
        goto b; // break after goto is useless
}

S_time = command[0].length;
b:
```

Comment: This is largely personal but I would fail this in a code review: it's not necessary *enough*. But you do set this out well, plus one.

Comment: It's `goto`, not `GOTO`. C++ keywords are case-sensitive.

Comment: Sorry, but the goto in the code above is not necessary, but evil. I write code for almost 20 years now (13+ years as a profession) and have never seen a code segment where goto is a necessity, but I can imagine one, but this simply isn't the case.

Comment: @mg30rg `goto` above is modification of author's example with minimal changes. I write code for almost 30 years if this is important. And ask yourself - not only "Why `goto` exists in C" but also "Why there is no Warning when using `goto`"? Because it is not evil :) And may help in many cases.

Comment: @i486 Minimal changes are important mainly for version tracking,and the OP's code would never make it into production code at any sane enterprise, so it doesn't need to be changed in an easily traceable manner. Goto exist in C for legacy reasons - there was a time when the compiler wasn't smart enough, and the coder had to do the micro-optimization. There is no warning for _using goto_,because of legacy code. Most of the places I worked at there was a policy not to compile production code without "treat warnings as errors",so all legacy libraries should be refactored because of such a warning.

Comment: @mg30rg C++ compilers are newer than C. And there again (I think) is no warning for `goto`. The "problem" with `goto` comes from academic community and teachers without practical experience as programmers.

Comment: @i486 I'm no information scientist, but a humble coder with 13+ years of field experience and I only found use for `goto` in languages where no proper _loop management_ **and/or** (multiple) _selection management_ were available. I repeat, I can **imagine** a use-case for goto, but I never found one in well-organized code.

Comment: @i486 Also, C++ is newer than C only by some five or six years, and its not uncommon to see inline C code in legacy C++ applications. There are also library routines written before smart compilers and never refactored using goto-heavy code for sorting and searching routines, which wouldn't worth rewriting.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed it is wise to avoid `goto` if possible, and trust the compiler to make the optimisations for you. Even in your case there is an alternative, which avoids the code duplication:

```
/*possibly inline*/ void foo(/*pass necessary parameters*/)
{
    switch(command[0].cmd){
    case 0: // turn off
        s::s_off();
        break;
    case 1: // turn on
        s::s_on();
        break;
    case 4: // nop
        return;       
    }
    S_time = command[0].length;
}
```

Comment: That return statement is a huge assumption that the OP has no further processing to do. Not bad advise otherwise.

Comment: there's like 50 other things that are similar only for few cases, it could really benefit from optimization, i have 90% of MCU full, and that's not a good thing, since i only started.

Answer (score 2):

As far as optimizations go, profiling is the best you can do. But let's have a look at the generated assembly nonetheless, as that can be useful too. I'll use the following dummy declarations:

```
namespace s {
    void s_on();
    void s_off();
};

struct Command {
    int cmd;
    int length;
};

int S_time;
```

The first version of your code compiled with Clang at `-O3` produces:

```
foo(Command*):                        # @foo(Command*)
        push    rbx
        mov     rbx, rdi
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rbx]
        cmp     eax, 1
        je      .LBB0_3
        test    eax, eax
        jne     .LBB0_5
        call    s::s_off()
        jmp     .LBB0_4
.LBB0_3:
        call    s::s_on()
.LBB0_4:
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rbx + 4]
        mov     dword ptr [rip + S_time], eax
.LBB0_5:
        pop     rbx
        ret
```

While the second version, with `goto`, produces:

```
foo2(Command*):                       # @foo2(Command*)
        push    rbx
        mov     rbx, rdi
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rbx]
        cmp     eax, 4
        je      .LBB1_6
        cmp     eax, 1                # These two instructions
        je      .LBB1_4               # weren't here in the first version
        test    eax, eax
        jne     .LBB1_5
        call    s::s_off()
        jmp     .LBB1_5
.LBB1_4:
        call    s::s_on()
.LBB1_5:
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rbx + 4]
        mov     dword ptr [rip + S_time], eax
.LBB1_6:
        pop     rbx
        ret
```

Not as clear as some other cases, but there is *one* difference: the first version only compares `command[0].cmd` with `0` and `1`, but the second one compares it with `0`, `1` *and* `4`. Less code repetition does not necessarily mean more optimised code: you have actually hindered the optimiser and made it generate a useless special case for `4`.

`goto` is not the low-level tool imbued with a magic low-level optimisation aura that its detractors describe. It's just a very basic flow control tool, which has few (but still some!) uses in C++ when the other tools don't cut it. It can, of course, be used for optimisation, but no better or more easily than any of the other ones.

Comment: thank's but i'm using atmel avr, so the assembler is different, also there is a ton of code that get's used, plus -O3 produces smaller size in avr GCC, but the code runs poorly, so I'm using just general optimalization. :D

Comment: also I'm doing checks for performance and size of final assembly, it's cool to see someone who does that too. :D

Answer (score 0):

The use of `goto` should be to make the code clearer. Not more complex. This is why for example goto out of a deeply nested set of loops or if-conditions would be acceptable sometimes, but using `goto` to "optimise" the code like in the example in this question is not a particularly good cause - it doesn't make the code clearer, rather the other way.

There are OFTEN other solutions - breaking something into smaller functions [often a good thing anyway] or restructuring the code. But if you end up with more complex code thanks to "avoid goto at all costs", then you are probably going the wrong way.

This question exemplifies a case where using goto MAY indeed be a better choice than the one chosen in the question itself:
[What are some better ways to avoid the do-while(0); hack in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507518/what-are-some-better-ways-to-avoid-the-do-while0-hack-in-c)